# Is there any css to height 100% despite bottom urlbar in iPhone emulator

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone

everyone
I am going to fill fullscreen my modal in my react project's mobile version.
I have just added CSS h-100 and in iPhone(iphone12, iOS 15) emulator, it is cut by urlbar and scrollbar is showing.
pls help me.
I have tried following

```
App.js
const appHeight = () => {
    const doc = document.documentElement
    doc.style.setProperty('--app-height', `${window.innerHeight}px`)
}
window.addEventListener('resize', appHeight)
appHeight()
```

```
App.css
:root {
  --app-height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
      height: var(--app-height) !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: `height 100%` means `100%` of the aprents height. The bodies height however s calculated to `fit-content`. What you proberly actually want to use is `body { min-height: 100vh; }`. Note that most browser add a default 8px amrgin to the bdoy that will cause a scrollbar to appear. As such you should reset the default margin.

Comment: @tacoshy, thank you for your reply. I think you have misunderstood my question. when i set 100vh is viewport height and urlbar size involves in that. so when 100vh set, there must be scrollbar